# Users are confused and think search filter are input boxes. How best to indicate that they are for filtering search results?

Tags: user-behavior, filter, help, intuitive

Users are confused and don't understand the boxes on top of the summary page are for further filtering the results. Some think the boxes are to enter new values. **What is the best way to indicate these are search/filter options?**

[image]

Comment: Placeholder text works

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use placeholder, but be try to be specific about the input type as well:

[image]

**Try reversing the stripes**

Another approach is to remove the tiger striping from the row, and use the background for the filter bar, to emphasize its 'separateness' from the data itself.

[image]

Normally dropdown lists use 'Select...' to indicate more UI (a menu), but you might try using the word 'Filter...' and test on users.

#### Another option: move the filters to a bar above the table

In this approach, you can be explicit w/ a filters label, and if there are common columns to filter on, you can order those any way you like. This pattern is useful if you have a data table with lots of columns that don't fit in the viewport (but some might have a filter).

You'll see this approach in Google Flights. It's not a spreadsheet like UI (it uses fat rows), but users can see at a glance if there's a filter engaged.

[image]

Comment: Great suggestions/options. Thank you Mike.

Answer (score 2):

Put a Search/magnifying glass icon and text label inside the boxes

Alternatively, add a Search/Filter icon/text & don't show the fields by default, until the user clicks the option.

[image]

Comment: Thank you c. That is a great option. Now I have to figure out how to do this using Yii!